# reorder fields on user profile page

Tags: forms, users

I can't find any solution to reorder some fields on user profil pages (like user/%/edit). At first I see User photo and language options. But in field options I have set another fields to be applied to the first position.

I have no possibility to move some fields to wished position. 
Have you any advice, how to do it? Thank you very much. Peter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to "Admin > Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage display". You will be able to reorder the fields from there. If you want to remove some of them from the display, you can select "Hidden" from the menu in the "Format" column.

**EDIT:**
The profile picture, however, is managed separately by Drupal, not as a field. If you want to be able to manage it, a workaround might be to disable the default Drupal profile picture (Admin > Configuration > People > Accounts > Personalization) and to create a new Image field to display the picture, which you can treat as any other regular field. There are even some modules that create the field for you, like [user picture field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_picture_field).

Comment: no, it doesn't work. Some field that can not be deleted, are also can not be reordet. And I see no field, like profile foto, I think it has to be modified via hook.

Comment: @user52660, you are right about the profile picture, I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the Content types page **(Administer > Structure > Content
   types)**.
2. In the table, locate the row that contains your content type and
   click the manage fields link.
3. Locate the field you want to re-order, and drag the four-headed
   arrow icon up or down.
4. Click **Save**.

[image]

When users create an Article, they will now see the Image field displayed immediately after the Title field:

[image]

**OR**

You can do it by editing `user-profile.tpl.php`

and arrange fields as your requirement like:

```
 <?php
 print render($user_profile['field_age']); 
?>
```

Comment: yes, but it's not the user profile form - user/%/edit. Here i have some fields, that can not be removed or moved to rigth position.

Comment: i am edit answer check it